# Dynamicaly added form fields - pdo php msql

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I made with jquery a dynamicaly added form field and works perfect but cannot make the db post. I use pdo php. It posts nothing but i can't figure out why.  Please help me but only with pdo and prepared statements, no mysqli! Thank you!

```
$number = $_POST['skill[]'];
if($number > 1)
{
    for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)
    {
        if(trim($_POST['skill[$i]'] != ''))
        {
            $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO skills (username, skillname) values (:username, :skill)";

            $pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($pdoQuery);

            $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(


                ":username" => $username,
                ":skill" => $number[$i]

            ));


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: _"only with pdo and prepared statements, no mysqli!"_ 

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple form controls with name attributes like this (whether they were dynamically added or not):

```
<input type="text" name="skill[]">
```

That doesn't translate to `$_POST['skill[]']` in your PHP code. It will just be `$_POST['skill']`, which will contain an array of all the values entered in the inputs with those names.

---

Assuming that is what you have:

First, prepare the statement before the loop. Re-preparing the same statement for each execution loses the performance benefit of using a prepared statement.

```
$pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO skills (username, skillname) values (:username, :skill)";
$pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($pdoQuery);
```

Then, just iterate `$_POST['skill']`. If there's nothing in it, the contents of the loop will never run.

```
foreach ($_POST['skill'] as $skill) {
    if (trim($skill)) {  // you don't have to explicitly check for '', because '' == false
        $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute([
            ":username" => $username,
            ":skill" => $skill
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, as usual. Note the initial `if`, I think they missed `count()`, right?

Comment: Thanks, Syscall. Yes, based on the subsequent code I assumed that was the intent even though the actual count was missing.